# Dell 7559 Laptop Display yellowish colors

Tags: display, dell-inspiron, display-settings

I recently bought an dell 7559 laptop , I am facing an issue with its display , i can see pure white color as yellowish why?

Can you help me please ?

**SMALL FIX -**

change blue color contrast in intel hd graphics property - but this won't completely remove the yellow color.

Comment: If you consider the answer below to be suitable, then please click the gray tick beside it.

Answer (score 0):

Your GPU sends out the image data to the display, but the display doesn't receive all of the blue (in RGB) for some reason.

Plausible cause: Wiring to... or the display itself ... is damaged.
*(or even the GPU; especially if it has been running hot, been warm for long)*

Comment: No The GPU is NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX

Comment: Well, makes no difference, I removed the mention of the Intel stuff for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

SMALL FIX -

change blue color contrast in intel hd graphics property - but this won't completely remove the yellow color.